# Changing the title of a link in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link with id "helpTopicAnchorId".

I want to change its text in jQuery.

How do I do this?

Comment: The `title` attribute is a tooltip that appears when you hover over a link. Do you really want to change that, or did you want to change the text of the link?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#helpTopicAnchorId').text('newText');
```

P.S the [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) make great reading

Comment: +1 for a link to the docs. They are quite good, and tend to answer 90% of the jquery questions in here.

Comment: I rely also on visualjquery.com. I saved a local version of the site (1 html page and related files) for easy ref.

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to the title attribute that can be used for tooltips, this works:

```
$('#helpTopicAnchorId').attr('title','new title');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.title = "your title here"
```

should do it

Comment: it doesn't use jquery